# Javascript works on IE but not on Firefox and gives me error as Error: cprofiledetailscollapse is not defined

Tags: c#, javascript, firefox

I use C#.net.
I wrote JavaScript for hide and show expand and collapse div accordingly. It work well in IE but not on Firefox, not even call the JavaScript function and gives me error as Error: ctl00_cpContents_dlSearchList_ctl08_profiledetailscollapse is not defined.
My JavaScript is as follows

```
function displayDiv(divCompact, divExpand) {
        //alert('1');
            var str = "ctl00_cpContents_";
            var divstyle = new String();
//            alert("ibtnShowHide" + ibtnShowHide);
            divstyle = divCompact.style.display;
            if (divstyle.toLowerCase() == "block" || divstyle == "") {
                divCompact.style.display = "none";
                divExpand.style.display = "block";
//                ibtnShowHide.ImageUrl = "images/expand_img.GIF";
            }
            else {
//                ibtnShowHide.ImageUrl = "images/restore_img.GIF";
                divCompact.style.display = "block";
                divExpand.style.display = "none";
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Since the problem is when you *call* the function, the relevant code to show would be where you're *calling* the function, not the function definition. Although having the function definition is useful as well, it's where you **call** it that's most relevant.

Comment: He's right, the code you've posted isn't generating the error ... and why do you need the "str" variable at the top? (trick question, you don't need it) :P

Answer (score 3):

ctl00_cpContents_dlSearchList_ctl08_profiledetailscollapse is an element id generated by ASP.NET. It's a profiledetailscollapse control inside dlSearchList.

JavaScript variable "ctl00_cpContents_dlSearchList_ctl08_profiledetailscollapse" is not
defined. Firefox does not automatically create, for each element with an id, a
variable in the global scope named after that id and containing a reference
to the element.

You might want to consider using jQuery to make sure that your DOM manipulation is cross-browser compatible.